# TFS Mapping Issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control, tfs

I have a project named "**MyNewProject**". The project was first located on my local machine at the location of: C:/Projects/MyNewProject/MyNewProject.sln

We then had Team Foundation Server (TFS) installed.  I wanted to put this project into a Collection called "Test". We created a new Project called "MyNewProject".  Before I put this into the Project, I copied the folder MyNewProject located in **C:/Projects/** and copied it to **C:/TFS/** so that it was separate from the original.

**Here is my question:**

When I open the original copy located in C:/Projects, it believes that it is associated with the project in TFS, even though the TFS Project is MAPPED to the C:/TFS/MyNewProject.  When I disconnect from TFS, it says it will close all projects that are associated with TFS and it closes the C:/Projects/MyNewProject.

What am I doing wrong!?

**EDIT**:  In the "Source Control Explorer" I click on the Project Name "MyNewProject" and the Local Path says "Not mapped", but when I click on the folder below the project name, the Local Path says "C:\TFS\Test\MyNewProject".

Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: Any specific reason you're using tfs for source control? There are many better options out there that give a lot more power and freedom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your mappings. A solution should only think it is under source control if its folder is mapped and its bindings have been set up.

That (and your comment about the single subfolder thinking it its mapped) suggests that your projects folder (or a subfolder) is mapped to tfs. So check that the mappings only mention the tfs folder. Go to the source control drop-down, and choose to edit the mappings.